# sql: set connection timeout in the connection string

Tags: sql, connection-string, connection-timeout

In a console app I have a connection string like this:

```
Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=database_name;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=100
```

I've read [here](https://www.connectionstrings.com/all-sql-server-connection-string-keywords/) that I need to add **`Connect Timeout`**  to the connection string to set the timeout, but if I run a query that contains

```
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:40';
```

I'll get a timeout exception, so it seems that the timeoput from the connection string is ignored. so how to set the timeout in the connection string (and not on the connection or command objects)?

Comment: How are you using this? Through a SqlConnection object? There is a Timeout property on that you can set instead....

Comment: but I need to set the timeout only in the connection string, because this string will be used to create many connections...

Comment: the connect timeout in the string only affects how long it takes to CONNECT to the server, not to execute queries. The only way is to set it on the SqlConnection and SqlCommand object sorry

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two timeouts relating to SQL connections/commands - there is a *connection* timeout, that affects how long a connection is willing to wait when you try to open it, and a *command* timeout that affects how long an individual command being executed will wait.

You need to adjust the second of these - by e.g. setting the `CommandTimeout` property on the `SqlCommand` object.

Comment: and is there a way to set the command timeout in the connection string or not?

Comment: I've never heard of that.  But that doesn't mean there isn't.  Didn't you say it worked (i.e. threw a timeout exception)?

Comment: @BudaGavril - no, there is not. The default 30 seconds is not unreasonable. It should be an *exceptional* situation where you need to set a longer/infinite timeout.

Comment: yes, I am creating an index on a very big table (more than 4 giga is only the table)...

Comment: @BudaGavril - yes, so you need it *for that command*, not for *every* command run against the connection.